# using history.pushState in Firefox make my favicon disappear

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, pushstate, html5-history

using something like

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, "?#");
```

in my site make my favicon disappear in Firefox, But it works in chrome

Is it a javascript/jQuery way to add favicon when the page is loading?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @DilipRajkumar yes it solved for me, it's weird but when i upload my site to my server, The problem solved.

this issue for me only happens when my site run locally

Comment: For me it happens on server too..:(

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue in IE. Whenever I called history.replaceState() favicon disappeared. Favicon was included via link tag like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/resources/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

After I placed favicon.ico to the root folder of my application and removed link, which pointed to it, problem with calling history.replaceState() disappeared. Hope that helps.